# pdf = rs.getBytes("pdf"); it not working in windows os .what is the alternate for read binary data from postgres bytea field

Tags: linux, windows, postgresql-9.0, struts2

this code when i write in the linux it will work fine but in  windows it is porduceing the double size of actual data in windows OS.will any one suggest me write solution.

Comment: Error message? Java and PgJDBC versions? Please show the code, the stack trace, and anything else you can think of. Is the PostgreSQL version the same on both OSes? Are you connecting to the same server, or is it a Pg server on Windows and a separate Pg server on Linux?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have not [multiple versions of PostgreSQL drivers](http://postgresql.1045698.n5.nabble.com/Inconsistent-Loading-of-Bytea-accross-platform-td3293637.html) in your Windows OS